How to interpret the Coefficient of nonlinear regression in scikit learn?
I am using the following code to do a nonlinear regression, and I am getting an intercept & 20 coefficients. How to interpret those coefficients to be able to construct a formula  Y = intercept + coeff*feat_a + .....?
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Step 2: Preprocess the data
X = data[['feat_a', 'feat_b', 'feat_c', 'feat_d', 'feat_e' ]]  # Independent variables including blue (b)
y = data['Y']

#splitting Train and Test
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=101)

# Dependent variable

# Step 3: Fit a polynomial regression model
degree = 2  # Adjust the degree of the polynomial as needed
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree, include_bias=False)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X_train)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_poly, y_train)

# Step 4: Evaluate the model (optional)

# Step 5: Extract the formula and parameters
intercept = model.intercept_
coefficients = model.coef_

print("coeff size{}".format(len(coefficients)))
print(coefficients)


import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# 3 features, 100 samples
feature_names = ["feat_a", "feat_b", "feat_c"]
X = np.random.random(100 * 3).reshape(100, 3)
y = np.random.random(100)

# create polynomials
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=True)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)

# train model
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
model.fit(X_poly, y)

# print trained formula
poly_feature_names = poly.get_feature_names_out(feature_names)

coef_strings = [f"({coef:.2} * {name})" for name, coef in zip(poly_feature_names, model.coef_)]
print("Y = " + " + ".join(coef_strings))

This will print something like (your coefficients will be different):
Y = (0.67 * 1) + (-0.74 * feat_a) + (0.34 * feat_b) + (-0.35 * feat_c) + (0.41 * feat_a^2) + (0.33 * feat_a feat_b) + (0.4 * feat_a feat_c) + (0.24 * feat_b^2) + (-1.0 * feat_b feat_c) + (0.43 * feat_c^2)
Please note that in creating PolynomialFeatures class we used include_bias=True so that constant component is included in features and than we used in LinearRegression parameter fit_intercept=False. This way we can only use coef_ and we don't need to combine it with intercept_ parameter.
